# Contact form7 from email is not overriding SMTP Envelope-From Email Address

Tags: wordpress, smtp

I have a problem with easy wp smtp on wordpress

I have entered the sender’s email address in the plugin field, but the email that the user receives when filling out the site's form (contact form7) has the SMTP User Name as sender, and not the email address I entered.

Anyone had encountered the same problem?

In the field
Sender email address I entered the same email address as the contact form, and as sender name I entered my name (present in cf7)

I entered the smtp host, ssl / tls, 465 port, Authentication smpt “yes”, the smtp username (name@domain.it) and the psw.

I have used other plugins that should have overwritten the email, but I have not seen any changes.

thank u very much

Comment: This sounds like a question for plug-in support.

Comment: I tried to ask but got no answer ...
in case i had tried to add this code in function.php:

 
function wpb_sender_email ($ original_email_address) {
     return 'tim.smith@example.com';
}

add_filter ('wp_mail_from', 'wpb_sender_email');

but no result

Comment: wp_mail_from would be overridden by your easy wp smtp plugin.  Consult their documentation or browse their code for overriding the SMTP info using filters.

Comment: I'll do it again! thanks anyway :) if i know anything i will write for updates